# Setting the property in a Map

Tags: groovy

I have a String variable `c` that I want to set in a map.

```
def c = "tony"
def methinks = [c:"bb"]
```

I want `methinks[tony] = "bb"`

but I get

```
methinks[c] = "bb"
```

Any tips

Comment: honestly, I didn't get what it supposed to mean:
`I want methinks.[tony] = "bb"

but I get

methinks.[c] = "bb"`

Comment: I asked question incorrectly. Sorry I have updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all works as expected:

```
def methinks = [:]
c = "tony"
methinks[c] = "bb"
assert methinks.tony == "bb"
```

After question update:

You need to escape `c` variable because it will be treated literally (as `c` sign)
See:

```
def c = "tony"
def methinks = [(c):"bb"]
assert methinks.tony == 'bb'
```

Comment: I asked question incorrectly. Sorry, I have updated.

Comment: Update answer, You understand it now?

Answer (score 4):

You can access map values with dot notation or with `[]`. It seems that you've mixed it up :) You can do it like below:

```
def methinks = [:]
c = "tony"
methinks."$c" = "bb"
assert methinks."$c" == "bb"
```

or:

```
def methinks = [:]
c = "tony"
methinks[c] = "bb"
assert methinks[c] == "bb"
```

As you can see the second version looks definitely better.

**After question update:** You're still mixing notations but @Opal provided exact solution to your problem.